# Exactly how are Avenger elites buffed when one of them dies?

Tags: diablo-iii

I understand that elites with the **Avenger** property get stronger as the others in the pack with that property die, but how exactly do they get stronger?

I'm looking for hard numbers.

Answer (score 5):

> Only Champion monster types will spawn with the Avenger trait. If a
>   Champion touting this ability appears, it can imbue all other
>   Champions in the area with the same type of powers it spawned with,
>   increasing **movement** and **attack speed** and **damage** inflicted until the
>   foe is felled. This effect may be **stacked up to three times.**

[Source](http://www.g4tv.com/thefeed/blog/post/724021/diablo-3-guide-rare-monster-traits/)

I highlighted the important bits.

Comment: That answers half the question, as far which attributes get upgraded. I'm still curious about how much of an upgrade they get, though.